How to find the expected value of $p_k$ in multinomial regression
Given a multinomial regression the probability of a certain class $k$ is a function of predictors. How would we find analytically the expected value of $p_k$ given we know the distribution of ${\bf X}_i$?
Multinomial regression as a log linear model:
$$
\text{ln Pr}(Y_i = k) = \beta_k \cdot{\bf X}_i - \text{ln} Z 
$$
$$
Z = \sum_{k=1}^K e^{\beta_k\cdot{\bf X}_i}
$$
$$
\text{Pr}(Y_i = k) = \frac{e^{\beta_k \cdot{\bf X}_i}}{\sum_{k=1}^K e^{\beta_k\cdot{\bf X}_i}}  
$$
The quantity of interest is $\mathbf{E}(\text{Pr}(Y_i = k))$. The conditional expectation: $\mathbf{E}(\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)|X_i))$ is not of interest and can be found by plugging in values for $X_i$
We can also specify multinomial regression as log odds with a reference category. Not sure which method is easier to work with analytically.
An example set up with one predictors and 3 classes:
$$
X_i \sim Norm(0,1)
$$
$$
\beta_1 = a, \beta_2 = b, \beta_3 = c
$$
$$
Pr(Y_i = k) = \frac{e^{\beta_k \cdot X_i}}{e^{\beta_1 \cdot X_i} + e^{\beta_2 \cdot X_i} + e^{\beta_3 \cdot X_i}}
$$
Any tips for going about this problem?

It looks like you have an explicit equation giving $
\text{Pr}(Y_i = k) = \frac{e^{\beta_k \cdot{\bf X}i}}{\sum{k=1}^K e^{\beta_k\cdot{\bf X}_i}}
$. Wouldn't you calculate from that?

@Dave—I think the issue is that $X$ is random, so the OP wants the expected value.   I'm not sure what the genesis of this problem would be, though, since typically we want the probability conditional upon $X$.

@jbowman I am doing some simulations with a more complicate model. Knowing the expectation is handy to know to compare estimates.

@Vefeagins Expected value of what? Do you mean the expected value of $
\text{Pr}(Y_i = k) = \frac{e^{\beta_k \cdot{\bf X}i}}{\sum{k=1}^K e^{\beta_k\cdot{\bf X}_i}}
$ across all values of $X$? Do you have some kind of Bayesian setup? It isn't clear what expected value you want to know, because there is a strong case to be made that $
\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)
$ itself is an expected value.

$ \text{ln Pr}(Y_i = k) = \beta_k \cdot{\bf X}_i - \text{ln} Z $ is a random variable dependent on $X_i$. I think just plugging in $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_i]$ should result in the expectation of the probability but I am unsure

No, because the denominator is also a function of random variables.

It might help if you write in regular English what you want to calculate. For instance, if you just want to know the probability of an outcome being event $k$ across all observed $x$-values, you already have that by calculating the proportion of times event $k$ happened.

$\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)$ is a constant, so $\mathbb{E}\left[\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)\right] = \text{Pr}(Y_i = k)$ itself, which is calculated by considering how many totaly observations there are and the proportion that that are event $k$ (e.g., there are roughly $10%$ sevens in the MNIST digits). I have a feeling you don't mean this, however, so I am reluctant to post this as an answer.

$\text{Pr}(Y_i=k)$ is a constant when we condition on $X_i$.  Otherwise, it is a random variable.

Marginally, $Y_i$ is a multinomial distribution, with $\text{Pr}\left(Y_i = k\right)$ as one of the multinomial distribution parameters that you can estimate through any of the many estimation methods. If you see $\text{Pr}\left(Y_i = k\right)$ as more complicated than this, please elaborate on what you mean, such as if you want to use a Bayesian approach and put a prior on the multinomial parameters and wind up with a posterior distribution.

@Dave, I am interested in an analytical pen and paper result no estimation necessary.

You have to estimate the $\beta$ coefficients, don't you?  (Maybe not...)

@jbowman this example is a population model all parameters are known.

To find the expectation ${\bf E}[\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)]$ would need to do calculus.
Since $\text{Pr}(Y_i = k) $ is a function of $X$ We can use the law of the unconscious statistician.
$$
{\bf E}[\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)]=  \int_{-\inf}^{\inf} g(x)*f(x) dx
$$
Where
$$
{\bf E}[\text{Pr}(Y_i = k)] = \int_{-\inf}^{\inf} \frac{e^{ax}}{e^{ax} + e^{bx} + e^{cx}}*f(x) dx
$$
Where $f(x)$ is the probability density function of normal distribution. I do not know how to tackle this problem analytically but that is the set up.
